# Seeking downloadable practice files for High Holiday Shacharit practice

Tags: product-recommendation, chazzan-prayer-leader, shacharis-morning-prayer, high-holidays

IY"H, I shall be the *Shaliach Tzibbur* for 2nd day Rosh Hashanna Shacharit and Yom Kippur. I feel that I know the nuscah well, as I have been doing this for many years. However, I could use some tunes for the "ark opened" *piyutim* which tend to have their own tunes.

Can someone recommend some *free* sources that are easy to follow and designed more as a "training" / tutorial rather than listening to a chazzan "yodel" that is easy to follow and that I can download to my Droid Maxx?

If you can, please explain why you recommend your choice.

Our shul uses Art Scroll Nusach Ashkenaz.

Comment: Still haven't found anything better than virtualcantor.com

Comment: Virtual Cantor is a great resource. I believe their files can be downloaded onto Android if you long-press and select Save File.

Comment: @Yitzchak I viewed the site last night and listened to a few files. Very nice. This will do. The guy's voice is a bit "shleppy"; I don't know how much I would like listening to him as the chazzan of my shul. But, for puroses of learning, this is really good and easy to follow. Musically, I didn't realize how difficult it is to sing *Avot* (beginning of chazarat hashat'z)!